# Restrict Upload file size in server

Tags: php, linux

I need to restrict upload file size via .htaccess to 50 kb. Because someone keep on uploading files my server without my knowledge. Is it possible to restrict 50kb or below? Whenever I need to upload files I  can change the limit. Or else is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: I would advise you to find out how someone is uploading stuff to your server - you should concentrate on fixing this issue first

Answer (score 0):

Insert this in your htaccess file

```
php_valueu upload_max_filesize 50kb
php_value post_max_size 50kb
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that,I edited answer